# How can I trigger a lambda function from a Kinesis stream reshard?

Tags: aws-lambda, aws-event-bridge, amazon-kinesis

I need to perform some processing in the event of a reshard of a Kinesis stream. I want to trigger a lambda function after shards are added or removed. I looked at EventBridge 'Events from AWS Services' (https://docs.aws.amazon.com/eventbridge/latest/userguide/eb-service-event.html) but see nothing which will help me there. I wondered if anyone knows how I might achieve this?

Comment: Given I've received no answers I thinking the only way to detect this is to use a scheduled Lambda. The Lambda would store the previous shard state and then would trigger event(s) when it determines a change between the current and previous state. Not ideal but it'll work.

Comment: If I reshard using CDK then this might allow me to acheive the automation I'm looking for: https://aws.amazon.com/about-aws/whats-new/2022/11/event-driven-applications-cloudformation-stacksets-event-notifications-eventbridge/